# Angular resolve company name from company ID in a loop

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, rxjs

I am new to angular and rxjs, i want to resolve `company name` from a `company id` in an array.

I have company data in this format:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      CompanyID      |     CompanyName  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1234       |    CompanyA      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5678       |    CompanyB      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And my angular codes:

```
  let items = [];
  let companyIDs = [1234, 5678];

  companyIDs.forEach(companyID => {
    this.items.push({
      compId: companyID,
      compName: ??? <------- how to resolve the name from the companyID above?
    })

  });
```

I have a service that returns RXJS `observable` that let me to resolve the `company name`

```
this.companyService.getCompanyName(1234).subscribe((companyName) => {
      //return CompanyA
})
```

How can i use the `companyService` to resolve company name?

---

**Edit:**
  I know it will be alot of requests calling `this.companyService.getCompanyName()` in a loop, any other suggestions like use `this.companyService.getCompanies()` instead is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a lot of http requests if you iterate your ID's and get a companyID for each. Nonetheless, this is what you can do to make your specific case into working:

```
companyIDs.forEach(companyId => {
    this.companyService.getCompanyName(companyId)
        .subscribe(compName => this.items.push({
             compId: companyId, compName: compName 
    })
});
```

the problem with this approach is that you have to make a service request per iteration, which means that an Array of 100 Id's would make it for a 100 http request, which is nothing close to ideal....

If it's possible for you to make an httpCall that gets you the whole table of ID's and Company Names in a table as shown in your question... such as `this.service.getAllCompanies() // return all the company objects with { id, name }`, then you could make that call and THEN iterate over the result, making it a simple http request.

Comment: Another potential problem is that the order of the elements in the array is not the same as the initial order of IDs.

Comment: @Francisco yeah actually think of that, still figuring out how to use `this.service.getAllCompanies()` to map the ids and return the name

Comment: if you have a way to call all the elements.. subscribe to it and map the result into a variable, or use the map pipe to change the structure of the response of the service (see rjxs pipes, and map specifically, to know the magic of this approach), if u have more questions do ask!

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
items = [];
 companyIDs = [1234, 5678];


      FillItems(){
        for(let i=0; i<this.companyIDs.length;i++){
          this.getcompanyname(this.companyIDs[i]);
        }
      }
      getcompanyname(companyid:number){
        this.companyService.getCompanyName(companyid).subscribe((companyName) => {

          this.items.push({
            compId: companyid,
            compName:companyName
          })
      }
```